# heroku app web constantly firing warning run id unauthorised

Tags: php, postgresql, heroku, laravel-5.1

I have an application deployed over heroku where I have paid for hobby dyno plan and a paid postgres instance.

My heroku pipeline is also completely set up where I have multiple apps running different versions of the application

The problem only rises in the paid app as below-

```
2017-06-05T11:00:24.816860+00:00 app[web.1]: 2017/06/05 11:00:24.816756 
(7) Warning: app "my-app-name" with run id "21****3840926*****" 
received unauthorized
```

On reporting this to heroku The only reply i have recived is that it's a problem with the application. By I am wondering if it's an application error why will it appear in only one instance and not in any other environment.

Also what I am not able to understand is what exactly it means by `run id`

Any help for the right direction will be great.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It was resolved,

The problem was with a dangling env config variable. An addon which was removed/expired still had the env config var set, making it throw the error.

The following process helped me debug the situation

- Code Review
- Dependencies check
- Bad Data(db related)
- Config Environment(.env)